# Android onDraw() is not getting called on Timer

Tags: android, android-canvas

This is in  GraphView.java which extends View. I want that when this invalidate(bounds) is getting called, at the same time it should call  onDraw().. What is bug in this code. It is giving me this exception.

> ```
>  01-01 00:45:42.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1586): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-2
>  01-01 00:45:42.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1586): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-01 00:45:42.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at          android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8467)
>   01-01 00:45:42.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):     at        com.cdl.mircam.GraphView$1.run(GraphView.java:327)
> 01-01 00:45:42.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1586):   at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
> ```

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c) 
    {
        super.onDraw(c);
        drawStuff(c);
    }


 public void drawStuff(Canvas canvas) 
   {    
   try
    {
        PlotRealTimeGraph(canvas);
        bounds = new Rect(chanX_count1+0, 0, chanX_count1+5, graphheight);
        canvas.drawRect(bounds,myPaint);
        }
   catch(Exception e1)
    {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }   


    public void InvalidatePlotRealTimeGraph()
     {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
       @Override
        public void run() 
        {
           invalidate(bounds);
        }     
      },1000,40);   
    }
```

Any help? please!!!

Comment: what is in GraphView.java at line 327 ?

Comment: @ Mocialov GraphView.java is file where i have written this code.This class extends View

Comment: great! what is at line 327?

Comment: invalidate(bounds); this call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
if(bounds != null)
   postInvalidate (leftOfYourBoundsObject, topOfYourBoundsObject, rightOfYourBoundsObject, bottomOfYourBoundsObject);
```

> PostInvalidate:
>
> Cause an invalidate of the specified area to happen on a subsequent
>   cycle through the event loop.

vs

> Invalidate:
>
> If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called
>   at some point in the future

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Comment: As much I know about postInvalidate(). It is not sure when it will call onDraw() again

Comment: @user1844130 you can test it :)

Comment: @user1844130 otherwise use `yourContextReference.runOnUIThread(new Runnable(...));`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing: `view.invalidate();` as it calls `onDraw(Canvas canvas)`.

Comment: @ Abhishek what is view here object of GraphView is it?

Comment: Pass the context to your activity in this view

Comment: Why are you passing null here?

Comment: public GraphView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {} this is my GraphView class  what should i do ?

Comment: use this: public GraphView(Context context )